# Cannot find module express in Yarn

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, yarnpkg

I'm trying to build a react app, which is built from the ground up. I use Yarn as my package manager. Whenever I try to run my node server I'm getting the error "Module not found express". which I did install and is a part of my dependencies.
I found out that the module express is being fetched from a node_modules directory instead of the local app directory, is this the issue?
[error description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFyWG.png)
The module is being fetched from here:

```
"C:/Users/hp/AppData/Local/Microsoft/TypeScript/4.2/node_modules/@types/express/index"
```

Thanks in advance :)

**EDIT**
NPM global screenshots
[image: one]
[image: two]
[image: three]
[image: four]
[image: five]

Comment: Did you perhaps install that package globally, with the `-g` flag?

Comment: I don't think so. If so what should I do to reverse it?

Comment: Can you try using `npm list -g` and post the results here, so I can help you debug it easier?

Comment: hey I did that and the list is too long and express is not in there, do u still want me to post those results, if so as screenshots or as text?

Comment: Screenshots are fine.

Comment: added @NicholasD

Comment: Well, that's strange. How did the module get fetched there? Have you tried deleting the `node_modules` folder and then reinstalling from scratch using `npm i`?

Comment: No I have used Yarn.